# Terraform local-exec stuck on "Still creating .." using az vm run-command

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

I am trying to run a "local-exec" command on Terraform 0.13.5 that runs a script inside a CentOS VM. This script (we'll call it utility-script.sh) just creates a log file and installs dnf. At the end of the script there is a `exit 0` line. Also tried `killall -u ${username}` but it still is stuck on "Still creating..". The `az vm run-command` command just hangs. This was working before but suddenly it just hangs now.

**Expectation:** To finish executing this command and move onto the next.

**Actual result:** Console shows "Still creating..." until timeout which is 90 mins on Azure.

```
resource "null_resource" "run-utility-script" {
  # Script execution happens after download
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.script-download
  ]

  # Create for each centos VM
  count = length(var.centos-vm-ids)

  triggers = {
    current_instance_id = var.centos-vm-ids[count.index]
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name ${var.centos-vm-names[count.index]} -g ${var.resource_group} --scripts \"echo ${var.password} | sudo -S chmod +x ${local.utility_script} ; echo ${var.password} | sudo bash ${local.utility_script}\""
  }
}
```

How can I fix this hanging issue?

Comment: Why don't you use a `remote-exec` provisioner instead of a `local-exec`?  https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html

Comment: Paste the script here. Also, if you want to run this script against the target machine, it has to be `remote-exec`. `local-exec` is executed on the controller machine.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use the [custom script extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension).